# How to access Firebase from http://localhost:3000

Tags: firebase, cors, firebase-authentication, cross-domain

I'm developing a React app, and I get this error when trying to sign in to Firebase using their email auth provider.

```
Failed to load https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key=.....: 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://localhost:3000' 
that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'http://localhost:3000'
is therefore not allowed access.
```

(Notice the `https` on line 3 versus `http` on line 4)

It looks like they changed `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` from `*`, to the `https` version of whatever domain you're calling from?

Does this mean I now need to configure my React app to run as **https**://localhost:3000?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to create a .env file in the root of your project and set HTTPS=true. This will launch your app using a self signed certificate.

Take a look at the advanced configuration options of create-react-app here

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#advanced-configuration

If you need more control over the certificate and do not want to eject. Take a look at react-app-rewired (https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired). You can config the devServer to use a custom certificate using the Extended Configuration Options here (https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired#extended-configuration-options)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)